# 403 : Access forbidden selenium

Tags: selenium, http-status-code-403

I want to run my testcases with the help of parameters mentioned in the testSuite.xml file and use them in my test cases by mentioning 
`@Parameters({ "selenium.host", "selenium.port", "selenium.browser", "selenium.url" })` in my code. 
Though, I started a standalone server with `-trustAllSSLcertificates`, the system is giving "403 access forbidden error". However, if I run the test cases individually, by hardcoding the port, URL, Host & browsername, it works fine.

Where am i going wrong?.....

BTW, I run my test cases using build.xml file. Here also i added the -trustAllSSLcertificates when starting the server. But still it does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

When running Selenium WebDriver using `selenium-server-standalone` I kept getting this error.

```
HTTP ERROR: 403
Forbidden for Proxy
RequestURI=/session
```

Turns out that it was because I needed to use the url `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` as the url for the RemoteWebDriver client to connect to.

I'm sure there are a number of things that could cause the `HTTP ERROR: 403`, but you may want to double-check that it's resolving to the correct base url.